# What is the difference between git push and git push origin

Tags: git, version-control

I'm having trouble differentiating between the two git statements, how exactly does one differ? Or do they differ at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` will git push to the default remote

`git push origin` will push to the remote named `origin`

When you clone a repository, the default remote is `origin` and it is automatically as the default upstream. That's why you may not see the difference.

Although, if you init a repo locally, `origin` won't be automatically created, e.g.:

```
git init
git remote add origin ssh://url/to/origin
git push -u origin --all # note there is also other way to set up the upstream
```

Note that the default remote could be named anything. `origin` is only a convention.

Comment: Beat me to it. One clarification to the statement "most of the time, the default remote is `origin`": the "most of the time" part here is when you use `git clone ...`, as in `git clone git://github.com/myname/myrepo`. In this instance, git automatically sets up the remote of `origin`.

Comment: git init always creates origin, check the git config files. Create some branches and then observe the config files growing.

Comment: @GhostRider Nope, `git init` won't create a remote named origin - it don't even know if there's a remote.

@acsmith Good clarification, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
**git push**
```

will directly push the commited changes to the branch on which you are currently present.

```
git push origin branchname
```

is used to specifically mention where should the code be pushed. It's always a better option to use this in all cases.

The keyword **origin** only references to the name used and can be changed in .git/config file in the project folder where git is initialized.

In case of adding a local project to remote. you can either use

git remote add ec2 ssh://username@path_to_project../home/ubuntu/ProjectDir.git

or

git remote add origin ssh://ubuntu@path_to_project../home/ubuntu/ProjectDir.git

The corresponding changes will be reflected in ProjectDir/.git/config file.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're quite wrong here. A remote is not a branch.

Comment: it depends in which context it's been used, either to add remotely or push changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have multiple remote places to push to. `git push` without any arguments to the push action, uses the default remote of the active branch. (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html and search for "origin").

Your current branch can be set up to track a remote repo (in which case `git push`, without origin, would push to that repo), but if there's nothing specified it tries for `origin`.

(This is why when using heroku, you generally have to `git push heroku`, instead of just `git push`.)